# How to use the <sms.svg> tag in Sublime Text 3

Tags: html, svg, sms, sublimetext3

When writing SVG into Sublime Text 3, one of the auto-complete options is:

```
<sms.svg></sms.svg>
```

It also has:

```
<skype.svg>
```

Does anyone know what these are or how to use them? Are these only icons or do they have any other uses?

Google does not return any results other than SMS SVG icons.

Not Sure if this helps anyone locate any documentation on these but the Current packages I have installed on Sublime are

```
A File Icon,
AngularJs,
BrowserRefresh,
Color Highlight Settings,
CssFontFamily,
Emmet,
Favourites,
GoogleSearch,
Hound,
Link Opener,
NpmInstall,
Package Control,
Package Dev,
Php Completions,
Php Constructors,
Plugin Debbuger,
Rust Enhanced,
Send Text,
SideBar,
SimplePHPUnit,
Trailing Spaces,
Anaconda Rust,
Babel,
Jasmin,
Live Reload,
NodeJs,
PrettyJson,
Sound,
SublimeCodeIntel,
ColorPicker..
```

That took alot longer than i expected...
If I had to guess out of All of these
I would expect it to be either Plugin Debugger or 
Package Dev.. But not 100% sure..

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages. Grammar is important on Stack Overflow, because the site is not a message board, it's more like an online reference book. Please help us by taking the time to use proper capitalization and spelling.

Comment: What package are you using to provide these completions?

Comment: I Can list the packages I have currently installed, But I have no idea of how to check which one would be currently doing the completion. I will Add these to the question.

Comment: They seem to be valid html tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are provided by the *A File Icon*. That's the first package in your listed packages.

Here's the Github Link & Documentation: https://github.com/SublimeText/AFileIcon